# Split words based on count in a sentence

Tags: regex, r, gsub

The idea is to split words in a sentence by a separator based on a given count of words. In this example, the count is 2:

```
  my.name <- c("Remi Whatname Say again")
```

the result should be:

```
  "Remi Whatname * Say again"
```

This is how far I could go:

```
gsub('([[:alpha:]]{2,})','\\1 *\\2',my.name,perl=T)  
> my.name
 "Remi * Whatname * Say * again *"
```

Any idea how to improve my pattern matching to reduce the replacement to only after 2 words in a row are detected? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> x <- c("Remi Whatname Say again", "Hi how ru?")
> gsub("(\\S+\\s+\\S+)\\b(?!$)", "\\1 *", x, perl=T)
[1] "Remi Whatname * Say again" "Hi how * ru?"
```

or

As @Mariano suggested,

```
gsub("((?:\\S+\\s+){2})", "\\1* ", x, perl=T)
```

Comment: @ Avinash: thanks it works just fine. Is there a way to generalize the process for any count cutoff/limit? In the example above, the limit was 2 consecutive words.

Comment: `gsub("((?:\\S+\\s+){2})", "\\1* ", x, perl=T)` and replace `{2}` with `count`.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching just for a string of characters of length at least 2, but not including a space. The simplest -although arguably not the cleanest is just add that requirement to what you already tried:

```
gsub('([[:alpha:]]{2,}[[:space:]][[:alpha:]]{2,})','\\1 *\\2',my.name,perl=T)
```

Comment: @ MASL: thanks for the feedback. I chose Avinash solution since the situation may get complicated if one needs to split on a limit > 2 word counts.

Comment: That's reasonable...to some extend. Notice that people here can usually only answer what you ask for, and you asked for 2w, not an arbitrary limit. Without making a drama out of it, it's a bit like cheating. Anyway, you can always up vote it; and next time try to remember to at least edit your question to reflect closer what you really want to solve.

Answer (score 0):

```
((?:(?:\\w+)\\s+){2})(?=\\w+)
```

You can use this and replace by `\\1*`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fW9yN5/1

Comment: @ vks: the regex live thing is one neat trick! thanks for sharing. Please see my comment to Avinash on generalizing the process to a given limit `n` on the word count.

Comment: @remi you can just replace `2` with anything u want.....you can generalise that easily